# How to use page breaks in pdf?

Tags: itext

How can I create a pdf using tables and page breaks?

[image]

Comment: Could you add code where you inserted the table?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Help us help you. Please take a moment to check the [tour], learn [ask]. Add details around what you already searched/tried, and a [MCVE].

Comment: *How can I create a pdf using tables and page breaks?* - what exactly is your problem in doing so?

Comment: You don't mention if you're using the old iText 5 (no longer supported if you're not a customer) or the new iText 7. Since you don't show any code, we can't tell, so it's hard to answer.